# How to Execute some coding when the enter key press in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using datagridview in winform.

If I press the enter key the selection is moved on row wise. But I want to execute some code which i write below:

```
try
{
    int dispin = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.DisplayIndex;
    if (dispin == 0)
    {
        string cellval = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
        returnParam = cellval;
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int colIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        colIndex = colIndex - 1;
        string cellval = dataGridView1[colIndex, rowIndex].Value.ToString();

        // MessageBox.Show(cellval1+cellval2+cellval3);
        returnParam = cellval;
        this.Close();
        //textBox1.Text = cellval;
    }
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Select a Record", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    //this.Close();
}
```

How to do this?

I am trying key down event, but it affect all key, please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `datagridview.KeyPress` Like:

```
//at form load:
dataGirdView1.KeyPress += OnDataGirdView1_KeyPress;

private void OnDataGirdView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
     { 
         RunMyCustomCode(); 
         //e.Handled = true; if you don't want the datagrid from hearing the enter pressed
     }
}
```

Comment: IT WORK BUT... it select the next record. bzs of the cursser moved to next record. then only this code is executed. how to solve this issue,

Comment: Try to add `e.Handled = true;` after or before `RunMyCustomCode()`

Comment: Thank you. i have use some code for stop row move while enter is down.

Answer (score 0):

```
void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
    { 
        e.Handled = true; 
    } 
}

void TextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        /* Your code here! */ 
    }
}
```